# How to recursively create subfolder in each folder of a directory in CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, mkdir

Let's say I have a directory called `Grandparent`
Inside this directory are multiple other folders, `Parent 1`, `Parent 2`, etc.. My goal is to create a new folder, `Child`, inside each of the `Parent` folders.

For example, what I have:

```
Grandparent/
    Parent1/
    Parent2/
    ...
    ...
    ParentX/
```

What I want:

```
Grandparent/
    Parent1/
        Child/
    Parent2/
        Child/
    ...
    ...
    ParentX/
        Child/
```

Is there a way to do this in CMD? (Note: I cannot download Powershell or any other convenient tool that would make my life easier, I am stuck with the default Windows Command Prompt)

**Update**

Following the links in the comments, I have tried the following:

```
for /r %%a in (.) do (
  rem enter the directory
  pushd %%a
  echo In Directory:
  mkdir testFolder
  cd
  rem leave the directory
  popd
)
```

However, this creates the folder `testFolder` in *every* newly created folder:

```
Grandparent/
    Parent1/
        Child/
            Child/
                Child/
                    ...
    Parent2/
        Child/
            Child/
                Child/
                    ...
    ...
    ...
    ParentX/
        Child/
            Child/
                Child/
                    ...
    Child/
        Child/
            Child/
                ...
```

Comment: Yes, but please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Recursively Visit Directories in a Directory Tree](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/3695/for-loops-in-batch-files/12871/recursively-visit-directories-in-a-directory-tree#t=201703251426285361546)

Comment: What did you try? show your code and explain what happened with it

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the link, that's a great place to start!

Comment: @yass I have updated my attempt and result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### However, this creates the folder testFolder in every newly created folder

This is because the `for /r` command is updating the list of files to process every time you create a new directory, so is really only useful if you want to visit a fixed list of directories.

Here is a batch file (test.cmd) that will do what you want. Place it in the `Grandparent` directory.

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /a:d`) do (
  rem enter the directory
  pushd %%a
  echo In Directory: %%a
  md child
  rem leave the directory
  popd
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- `dir /b /a:d` is evaluated once, so the list of directories is fixed
- `for /f` will loop through this fixed list exactly once.

Example output:

```
> test
In Directory: Documentation
In Directory: subdir
In Directory: test
In Directory: test with space
In Directory: test1

> dir /b /a:d /s child
F:\test\Documentation\child
F:\test\subdir\child
F:\test\test\child
F:\test\test with space\child
F:\test\test1\child
```

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [md](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html) - Make Directory - Creates a new folder.
- [pushd](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) - Change the current directory/folder and store the previous folder/path for use by the POPD command.
- [popd](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) - Change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the PUSHD command.